# MYSQL count duplicate value

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I want to count the same value on parent_id but not count if there is '0' value.

```
table:t_article
id_article      parent_id
441             0
1093            18
18              0
3141            3130
3130            0
3140            3130
3142            3130
```

Expected output

```
id_article      parent_id       Total
441             0               0
1093            18              1
18              0               0
3141            3130            3
3130            0               0
3140            3130            3
3142            3130            3
```

How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the total column to represent the number of children which a given `parent_id` has, which is coincident with the count of that `parent_id` value.  You may try joining to a subquery which finds the counts:

```
SELECT
    t1.id_article,
    t1.parent_id,
    COALESCE(t2.Total, 0) AS Total
FROM t_article t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM t_article
    WHERE parent_id <> 0
    GROUP BY parent_id
) t2
    ON t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: but if I want add same Total value on id_article which have the same value with parent_id, how to make it?
ex: id_article 3130 have Total 3, it's same with the parent_id itself

Comment: I don't know exactly what you have in mind.  It sounds like a recursive hierarchical query.  You might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using inner join and conditional aggregation

```
select a.*, b.cnt
from t_article a
join (
  select parent_id, sum(parent_id <> 0) cnt
  from t_article 
  group by parent_id
) b using(parent_id)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fe2ed/3)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid but if I want add same Total value on id_article which have the same value with parent_id, how to make it? ex: id_article 3130 have Total 3, it's same with the parent_id itself

Comment: @RahadianWiratama your comment isn't clear , Can you update your question or better if could ask a new one

Comment: @RahadianWiratama Now you have changed the logic of your question which makes answers posted for this question as invalid, I guess it would be good if you revert your question and ask a new one

Comment: @RahadianWiratama Yes that would be good for us and please do revert the details of your question, Tim i won't edit :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I made new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715267/mysql-count-duplicate-value-different-column

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query as well:

```
SELECT id_article,parent_id,(SELECT COUNT(parent_id) FROM t_article as t2  WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id AND t2.parent_id != 0 ) AS total  FROM `t_article` as  t1
```

**Result**

[image]