# Mysql count duplicate value different column

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I want to count the same value among parent_id and id_article, but it can be 0 if there is no same value among parent_id and id_article

```
table:t_article
id_article      parent_id
441             0
1093            18
18              0
3141            3130
3130            0
3140            3130
3142            3130
```

Expected output

```
id_article      parent_id       Total
441             0               0
1093            18              0
18              0               1
3141            3130            0
3130            0               3
3140            3130            0
3142            3130            0
```

How do I make it happen?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your count by doing a sub clause and then join with your main query

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.cnt,0)
from t_article a
left join (
  select parent_id, sum(parent_id <> 0) cnt
  from t_article 
  group by parent_id
) b on (a.id_article = b.parent_id)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fe2ed/12)